# How do I make a for...in loop to work inside a promise?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asynchronous

I am building an app where I fetch data from an API. I am using fetch method with a few .then()s to process the data. After I use a for...in loop to organize it and display it in the browser.

```js
//Fetch data from API
var dataD = document.getElementById('data');
var url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/starships/9/';
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  fetch(url).then(response =>
      response.json()
    ).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      const z = response;
      for (const key in z) {
        if (z.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          dataD.innerHTML = `${key} : ${z[key]}`
          console.log(`${key} : ${z[key]}`)
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(`error ${err}`))
})
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

In the for...in loop when I console.log key and z[key] the data shows organized and exactly how I expect it to show, which is the object keys first and then it's values, but in the app in the div it only shows url : https://swapi.dev/api/starships/9/ 
I can't understand why in the console it displays correctly and in the browser it won't.

Comment: You're over-writing the same `.innerHTML` over and over.

Comment: Thank you Mr Alnitak. So I guess I have to use push method?

Comment: That rather depends what you want your output to look like.

Comment: You could replace the whole `for ... in` loop with something like. `dataD.innerHTML = Object.entries(response).map(([key, val]) => \`${key}: ${val}\`).join("\n");` Though as Alnitak wrote, it depends...

Comment: I created an array and pushed each item into it and then displayed the whole array in the dataD div using join method. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you use innerHTML, you need to have a complete thing - you overwrite innerHTML again and again

Here I use a definition list

NOTE: You will need to recurse if you want to process the nested objects

```js
//Fetch data from API
let dataD;
const url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/starships/9/';
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  dataD = document.getElementById('data');
  fetch(url).then(response =>
      response.json()
    ).then(response => {
      const html = Object.entries(response).map(([k,v]) => `<dt>${k}</dt><dd>${v}</dd>`)
      dataD.innerHTML = html.join("");
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(`error ${err}`))
})
```

```html
<dl id="data"></dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```js
//Fetch data from API
var dataD = document.getElementById('data');
var url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/starships/9/';
var array = [];
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    fetch(url).then(response =>
        response.json()

    ).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        const z = response;
        for (const key in z) {
            if (z.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                array.push(`<h2>${key} : ${z[key]}</h2>`);
                dataD.innerHTML = array.join('');
            }
        }

    })
        .catch(err => console.log(`error ${err}`))

})
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Pushing key : value into an array and displaying it all at once in the div